# table collection view not sticking to the bottom layout xcode on ipad

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints, ios-autolayout

Hi guys so I have a table view that doesn't stick to the bottom for the ipad but it does on the iphone. It's a simple table view and it's constraint is basically 0 bottom, 0 leading, 0 trailing i'll attach the images here.

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwSda.png)

[the constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ezsr.png)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of strange behavior comes from scrollview insets, lets try this in your view controller:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```